# Catalan recurrence

Tags: combinatorics

Show directly that the number of configurations in the following problem satisfies the Catalan recurrence

- Sequences $(h_0,\dots , h_{2n})$ of $2n + 1$ non-negative integers $h_i$ such that $h_0 = h_{2n} = 0$ and
  $h_{i±1} = h_i ± 1$.

I am genuinely lost on this question and would like some tips if possible?

Comment: Please fix the indices if you can, since the problem is not very clear as written.

Comment: I think I have interpreted what you've written correctly. Please check that everything matches your original problem.

Comment: Yes thats correct interpretation, sorry for the messy indices.

Comment: One last question: what does the last condition imply? As I'm understanding it since $h_0 = 0$ and the integers are non-negative, it has to be increasing (and only by a factor of $1$) which would imply a unique solution. What am I missing? Do you mean that adjacent terms differ in $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Example sequences:

Comment: (0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0) or (0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0) or (0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0) or (0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0). or (0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0),

Comment: Great, got it. Thanks! I'll think about this.